# Difference between "I'm home" vs "I'm at home"

Tags: american-english, word-difference, spoken-english

What's the difference between these two sentences? And which one's grammatically correct?

Comment: Not enough context. At times these phrases are interchangeable, at times not.

Comment: I think something like: 1) *I'm home* = I just got in. 2) *I'm at home* = It doesn't imply I'm in, I could be outside of my home.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/im-home-or-im-at-home)?

Comment: No, i wasn't aware of the fact the question ssimilar to this already exists

Answer (score 8):

In the literal sense, both simply tell someone where you are. These would generally be used in slightly different contexts though.

If you are at home, and have been there for some time, and someone is asking where you are, you would respond "I'm at home".

You would use "I'm home" more to indicate that you just arrived there. Maybe to someone who was expecting you or wanted you to let them know you made it home safely.