# Home vs at home

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

1. I'm at home.
2. I usually take my breakfast home (without preposition).
3. I usually take my breakfast at home(or at my home ;with preposition)

In the first sentence, at home is an adjective preposition phrase. In the second sentence, home can be used as adverb. In the third sentence, "at home" can be used as adverbial prepositional phrase. Am I right? Are the three sentences correct? Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear whether you think 2 and 3 mean the same thing. 2 means you buy your breakfast somewhere, but eat it at home. Please see this previous question [Difference between “I'm home” vs “I'm at home”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83815/difference-between-im-home-vs-im-at-home), and this one [“I'm home” or “I'm at home”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/im-home-or-im-at-home)

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences are correct English. Exactly how you classify the parts of speech and grammatical structure is debatable (seriously, linguists debate this stuff).

However, sentence 2 and 3 have very distinct meanings, and actually make use of different senses of the verb *to take*.

> I usually **take** *my breakfast* **home**

Usually is an adverb, *take* is the verb, *my breakfast* is the direct object, and *home* the indirect object. The speaker is talking about moving their breakfast to their home.

> I usually take my breakfast **at home**

This uses an alternate sense of the verb *take* that is applied largely to food and drinks, though also exists somewhat similarly for things like tests and exams. *At home* is a prepositional adverb phrase indicating where the speaker *takes his breakfast*. To *take tea* is to have a drink of tea, possibly with accompanying light foodstuffs, and one might *take wine* with one's meal - as well as find gentlemen of prior centuries telling their family that they will be *taking their dinner* at their club. In the sense of food and drink, it could usually be replaced with *have* in the modern vernacular usage, or *eat* or *drink* as appropriate. In this case, the speaker is saying that they have breakfast at home, rather than away from home. The *my* is essentially extraneous, and does not affect the meaning.

Comment: You are saying that I'm home is correct. I know linking verb don't follow adverb. So, how Home (as an adverb) can be used after linking verb IS? I usually dance home vs I usually dance at home are they both correct? Has there different meaning? Thank you.